# How can I get the value of a hidden input field when submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a page with multiple forms on it. Each form has two submit buttons and one hidden input field which contains an ID.

When the user clicks one of the submit buttons, I need to send the value of the clicked submit button along with the value of the hidden input field with the form submission.

Here is an example of what my page looks like:

```
<form id="options">
<input type="hidden" value="104">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Reply">
</form>

<form id="options">
<input type="hidden" value="44">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Reply">
</form>

<form id="options">
<input type="hidden" value="39">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Reply">
</form>


<script>
$(document).on("submit", "#options", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(this.submitted) // gets the value of the submit button
});
</script>
```

Currently I can only send the value of the clicked submit button with the form submission and not the value of the hidden input field. While I am aware that I could use `onclick="this.form.submited=this.previousElementSibling.value;"` to get the ID, this would mean I cannot get the value of the clicked submit button.

Comment: Don't use the same `id` multiple times. An `id` is supposed to be unique. As far as I can see, this is clearly an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Also, hidden input values *are sent along* already. They are hidden from view, not the server.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/1186309#1186309

Comment: Wait, did you edit your code to remove the `name` attributes? I was talking about `id="options"`. You need `name="id"` so the data is accessible on the server end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to to get the hidden input of the current form, and you can't use the same `id` for multiple elements, change your `id` to `class="options"`.

```
var val = $(this).find('input:hidden').val());
```

```js
$(document).on("submit", ".options", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log($(this).find('input:hidden').val()) // gets the value of the submit button
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="options">
<input type="hidden" value="104">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Reply">
</form>

<form class="options">
<input type="hidden" value="44">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Reply">
</form>

<form class="options">
<input type="hidden" value="39">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Reply">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `val()`:

```
var value = $('input[name="input-name"]').val();
```

Edit:
If you want to use more than one input with the same `name`, use it like this:

```
$('input[name="input-name"]').forEach(function($in) {
    var value = $in.val();
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't give a name more than once in a single page. Name should be unique value.

Comment: How about we remove the `name` attribute all together.

Comment: @TamirNahum In case of form submit, where you are sending a data collection we need multiple input fields with the same name.

Comment: You can use the `forEach` function. I will edit my answer in a minute to give an example.

Comment: You mentioned `Name should be unique value`. Just need clarification on this.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's valid to put the same name for more than one input (as I mentioned - I'm not sure.. But you can Google it to make sure).
The above example should be your answer if you choose to use the same name for more than one input.

Comment: No, name does not need to be unique and regularly isn't, what about a set of radio inputs for example?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney You are correct. Ignore the last comments! Use the answer's examples :)

Comment: or you can skip the foreach and use `$(this)` which refers to the current form being submitted, and find the element with `.find()`.

Comment: You can relate to each input's value by using the `forEach` loop.

Comment: why loop over everything instead of finding it in the current form, seems like a waste of time.

Comment: @TamirNahum OP now has only three forms. But imagine a scenario where it might have more than 100 forms (Crazy scenario ! :D), the loop goes on increasing with form count increase. When just plugging one event can fetch you the data, why go through the tedious process of looping over all input fields in all the forms unnecessarily.

Comment: Using this `$('input[name="input-name"]')` is to catch any `input` with the name `input-name` in the webpage. Using the `forEach` loop or the jQuery function `each` is in order to take action with any single value of those inputs...

Comment: @TamirNahum getting any input with the name input-name in the current webpage, and get hidden input in this current form, which one is better?

Comment: You are not trying to get it within a single form. There are many forms in the webpage..

Answer (score 0):

Give an id say hiddenInput to the hidden input box. To access the value you can use `$(.hiddenInput).val();`. To access the value on the server side, you can access it using `req.query.id()`

Comment: Remember that there are multiple hidden input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='submit']").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var id = $(this).parent().find("input[name='id']").val();
     var action = $(this).data("action");
     console.log("action: " + action + ", id: " + id);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<form id="options1">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="104">
<input type="submit" data-action="delete" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" data-action="reply" value="Reply">
</form>

<form id="options2">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="44">
<input type="submit" data-action="delete" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" data-action="reply" value="Reply">
</form>

<form id="options3">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="39">
<input type="submit" data-action="delete" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" data-action="reply" value="Reply">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will fetch you the required data.

```js
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
  alert($(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val())
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="options">
<input type="hidden" value="104">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Reply">
</form>

<form id="options">
<input type="hidden" value="44">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Reply">
</form>

<form id="options">
<input type="hidden" value="39">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" value="Reply">
</form>
```

Comment: you can't use the same `id` for multiple elements.

Comment: @julekgwa Oh yes! I missed that. Actually, there is no need for the Id or the class. But cannot remove ID from the markup as it might be used in CSS.

Comment: maybe for styling

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="104">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Reply">
</form>
```

Clicking the `Reply` button yields:

> id=104&action=Reply